# How to change the data source in nova?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I need to create a page that extract data which come from a third-party API. I can't find a way to change the data source in order to make a nova resource read data from the API, not from my database, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: use guzzle http

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Nova Resources will only connect to a Laravel Model. However, there are ways to make a model represent an api using a mix of different packages and some ingenuity.

I would first set up a [Saloon](https://docs.saloon.dev/) integration for connecting to and pulling from the API data. This isn't strictly necessary, but is a great way to keep your third-party API client clean.

I would use the saloon connectors/requests/responses in an Eloquent model that has the [Sushi](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi) trait. This package allows a model to not be associated with a database table, and instead to use data returned from a method called `getRows()`. Inside `getRows()` is where I would connect to the API, consume what I needed to, and return the data.

Finally, I would use Laravels [Model Events](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#events) when saving or updating to send new data to the third-party api to update information.

This is high-level, and the details would be intricate so not appropriate for an SO answer - but hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.